# APEX office print Plugin - How to get the Download date/Creation date in template

Tags: excel, oracle-apex

I have a requirement where I need to provide the creation date of the excel in one of the cell, when it gets downloaded using the APEX office Print plugin in Oracle APEX.

I have created a interactive report template with tag '{&interactive}'. So along with the data in the report, I need to show the creation date/time of the report i.e. the date/time when it was downloaded.

I was trying to create a macro in the template but it seems macro is not supported by AOP template in APEX.

Can you please suggest, how to make it work without a macro.

Is there any way so that I can get the Creation date in one of the cell, when it gets downloaded from Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer on email by the creator himself. Hece sharing here.

The easiest way would be to add another classic report on the page and there you can for example do

```
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY') as dd, :APP_USER as username  
from dual
```

In AOP you reference the second static id then.

Note you might need to use {&interactive_1} and for the other region you would use {#static_id}{dd}{/static_id}

Hope this helps somebody !